# I only made a trivial edit to approve a more substantial one; why is my name shown as the editor?

Tags: support, edits

While approving a post edit, I made a small change in order to convert a word into *Code Sample*. However the post now shows my name under "edited" and not the original person whose edits I approved. Is there something that can be done to revert the situation and what should be done in those cases?

Comment: It always shows the last edit. Your edit was the last one made, so you show up on the post. All users are properly credited in the revision history

Comment: Thank you. Didn’t see something very obvious and thought it was also unfair to the other user who did the large portion of the edit

Comment: *"...convert a word into Code Sample"*: Is *Code Sample* a proper noun, in a headline, or literal?

Comment: @PeterMortensen _Code Sample_, is just the legend shown when hovering over `{}` in the post editor. This corresponds to back ticking text or just using `Ctrl/Cmd + K`, before typing. My post was certainly unclear and this point also created confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. The system only shows the usercard of the author of *the most recent edit*. Even though the edit you made was only a minor one, it is still (currently) the most recent to the post, so you are shown as the editor.

The full revision history, along with the names and diffs of all the edits, is always available by clicking the link text that begins with "edited" and contains a time-date stamp.

This is covered in the [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) article in the Help Center:

> **What happens when I edit a post?**
>
> The post will be updated to show the latest editor, as well as the original author. All edits are saved and tracked in a public revision history with attribution to each editor.
>
> The revision history can be viewed by clicking the date and time next to the edited post (e.g., "edited 3 days ago").

Comment: Thank you for both the edit and your answer. I obviously didn’t do my homework this time.

Comment: I *did* do my homework, looking for a duplicate because I can barely imagine that this hasn't been asked and answered before here on Meta Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find one, so I went ahead and answered it. Cheers!